# If a coin is tossed ten times, how many different ways are there for obtaining exactly eight heads?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I have been stuck over this easy looking question. The answer says,

> "There are as many different ways to obtain eight heads in ten tosses
>   as there are subsets of eight elements (the toss numbers on which
>   heads are obtained) that can be chosen from a set of ten elements."

But I really don't understand what is meant by "eight element subsets" of a "ten element set". If we obtain head on the $i$th toss then we denote it by $H_i$ and if we obtain tails on the $i$th toss then we denote it by $T_i$.

So, is the ten element set $\{H_1,H_2,...,H_{10}\}$ here? If so, then I will choose $8$ heads out of it in ${10 \choose 8}$ ways which is the answer. But then still why the ten element set is $\{H_1,H_2,...,H_{10}\}$ in this case? Why are not we considering two tails which are going to appear in ten tosses since we want exactly $8$ heads?

I am feeling like a stupid on this now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is one way to look at it. Another way to see it is that the ten element set is $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10\}$, and the eight you are supposed to choose from this is the eight numbers that will appear as indices to $H$ (the two remaining will appear as indices to $T$).

So, for instance, if the first eight were heads, and the final two were tails, then we have chosen the eight-element subset $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8\}$, and we get
$$
H_1, H_2, H_3, H_4, H_5, H_6, H_7, H_8, T_9, T_{10}
$$
The usual interpretation, though, is that "The first eight are heads and the two final tosses are tails" is denoted simply as
$$
HHHHHHHHTT
$$
in order, and without indices, which is to say, the ten-element set consists of ten spots like below:
$$
\_\, \_\, \_\, \_\, \_\, \_\, \_\, \_\, \_\, \_\, 
$$
and we want to know the number of ways to pick $8$ of them to put an $H$ in (and then the remaining two will get a $T$.

At any rate, the answer is $\binom {10}8$.

Comment: Good answer. Now I am out of this mess. Sigh!